# Maximo access monitoring

Tags: maximo

Is it possible to check which machine/IP address was used to access Maximo and enter data into a report?
For e.g. I have a lookup list of Names who have access to a user account (more than one person is logging in using the same username and password) and I want to know which PC was used to enter the details into the report. Is this doable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MAXSESSION table will keeps a running list of active sessions in Maximo.

A report based off MAXSESSION would only tell you the active sessions.

[Maxsession table functionality explained](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21511900)

[The MAXSESSION table unmasked](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/e25892f0-20f7-46ff-bbe9-c7c03fb3036f/entry/the_maxsession_table_unmasked1?lang=en)

The other option is to grep the SystemOut.log assuming you have Correlation Enabled.

[Get more out of maximo logs - log correlation in 7.5](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/a9ba1efe-b731-4317-9724-a181d6155e3a/entry/get_more_out_of_maximo_logs_log_correlation_in_7_54?lang=en)

Answer (score 2):

You could also try to make use of the `LOGINTRACKING` and `REPORT` tables.

This example shows all report run instances with associated logins by the user that ran the report within 2 hours of logging in.  It's not 100%, but it may help shed some light on what's going on.

Note, we're running on an Oracle database.

```
select 
    report.lastrunby, 
    to_char(Logintracking.Attemptdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as login_date, 
    Logintracking.Clienthost, 
    Report.Reportname, 
    to_char(Report.Lastrundate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as report_run_date
 from 
    report, logintracking
 where 
    report.lastrunby = logintracking.userid
    and Report.Lastrundate >= Logintracking.Attemptdate
    and Report.Lastrundate <= Logintracking.Attemptdate + 0.0832
```